# removeChild by element with PHP

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I want to remove the whole sticker node by calling the id 100.
But nothing happens really.
Any idea ?

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('../write.xml');

    $result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker[id="100"]');
    $result->childNodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($result->childNodes->item(0));

$xml->save('../write.xml');


      <stickers>
          <sticker> /* Remove */
            <text>Thaishi1</text>
            <id>100</id>
          </sticker>
            <sticker>
             </position>
            <text>Thaishi2</text>
            <id>200</id>
          </sticker>
        </stickers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If “nothing happens”, configure your error_reporting to a sensible debugging level – you should get warnings that there is no `->childNodes` property.

```
$result->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($result->item(0));
```

This should work.

Comment: This worked like a charm, I did what you said and changed the  error_reporting, remember now that i actually switched it down before.
Thanks again.